# Sweetalert - Get div content and show it there as text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I got an div called cart. JavaScript adds there div's each clicked item on page. So example: Website has Banana, Apple, Car. Then itemcart is empty, if person clicks on Banana then javascript adds `<div class=banana>Banana</div>`
Then you can click button Purchase which calls function purchase(). I want to add there that, if purchase() function called, then in that it will get content of that itemcart and get all items what are there and display them in sweetalert. Is that possible?

```
var itemcurt = $("#itemcart");
```

I tried that, but it just shows Object object..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Add some of your code, than we can help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#itemcart")` is a object you want its inner content so you may use

```
var itemcurt = $("#itemcart").text();
```

`.text()` will give the inner content in text form even if there are some tags in it then also everything will come in text

**For example**

```
<div id="itemcart">
   <div>text</div>
</div>
```

In above html if you use `.text()` then the div inside it will come in text form like this `&lt;div&gt;text&lt;/div&gt;`

If in case you have html tags inside it and want in html form then use this

```
var itemcurt = $("#itemcart").html();
```